# My REST GET requests doesn't send me all available data

Tags: python, json, rest

I believe it is an issue with my code rather than API provider.

This is how I make my request and store it in a JSON:

```
import json
import requests


def jsonify(url, filename):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, auth=(cfg.LOGIN, cfg.PASSWORD))
        content = response.json()
        with open(filename, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(content, file, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    except ConnectionError:
        print("API connection failed - wrong login/password?")
```

If I enter the API link in my browser, I'm seeing all the data there is. However if i open my .json file I can not find some elements.

There are no keys or values missing - only response elements.
This probably won't tell you much, but here are two example elements:

```
...
{
    "id":19535,
    "attributes":{},
    "groupId":0, 
    "name":"5349",
    "uniqueId":"5349",
    "status":"offline", 
    "lastUpdate":null,
    "positionId":0,
    "geofenceIds":[],
    "phone":null,
    "model":null,
    "contact":null,
    "category":null,
    "disabled":false
},
{
    "id":19525,
    "attributes":{},
    "groupId":0,
    "name":"4805",
    "uniqueId":"4805",
    "status":"offline",
    "lastUpdate":null,
    "positionId":0,
    "geofenceIds":[],
    "phone":null,
    "model":null,
    "contact":null,
    "category":null,
    "disabled":false
},
...
```

The first one is both in my browser and .json, the second is only in browser, not .json.

Comment: did you check the content of you variable `content`?

Comment: @wernersbacher I simply did `print(jsonify(url, 'test.json'))` and found this element. Very strange. One thing worth noting is that I don't remove json files after the job is done, I assumed the `'w'` tag does it for me. Could it be the issue?

Comment: @Vii-Man Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: `w` should really just overwrite the old file. Put also a `print(content)` in your function to check if it's a request or json problem.

Comment: @wernersbacher I did that, and I did find my missing element. It's very strange because whenever I refer to `jsonify()` in my script, I always do it the same way: `functions.jsonify(cfg.url, 'json/result.json')`

Comment: So you can absolutely say that from the step where all your data are in `content`, they aren't the exact same in the json file? If yes, try to convert your `content` to string and write that one to the file. if the problem persist, check the value of the generated json string.

Comment: @wernersbacher I removed my .json files and `__pycache__` folder, made new ones without changing my code - now I can see the missing element. It looks like some sort of caching issue. I need to find a way to remove such caching, but for now I'll just delete files before writing new ones...

Comment: ok. maybe a json.dump() problem. but yes deleting them is quite an easy workaround.